# Pyserial not writing correctly to text file

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a simple python script that will read serial data and decode it correctly in the IDE, but when trying to write this info to a text file for parsing, it appears incorrectly. Not sure why this is happening. I have attached my script and the output of the incorrect text file. I have tried `.decode("UTF-8")` and `.decode("ASCII")` with no luck. All suggestions are welcome.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import serial
import time
import io
import struct
import re

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=180)
port.flushInput()
print(port.isOpen())
print("Listening...")
test = port.read(1000)
readings = []
done = False
while not done:
    current_char = port.read(5)
    if current_char == b'Field':
        reading = port.read(1238)
        readings.append(reading)
    if len(readings) >= 10:
        done = True
        print(type(reading))
        print("..........Decoded bytes = ..........")
        decode_bytes = reading.decode()
        print(type(decode_bytes))
        print(decode_bytes)
        with open('test_data.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(decode_bytes)
            #f.close()
port.close()
```

What I am getting:

```
current 463.70A
[3;38H19:07:47 15-Sep-21
[4;20H02:00:00 
[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[16;20H1126R[16;36H1124R[17;20H1058R[17;36H1038R[18;20H127.1R[19;20H20.6R[19;36H20.8R[20;20H15.30[21;20H0.589W [3;38H19:07:48 15-Sep-21
[4;20H02:00:00 
[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[15;44H[0mOK   [0m
[20;44H[0mOK   [0m
[7m[8;6HHE WARN[0m           [0m[8;37HOFF[0m[0m[8;41H [0m[0m[8;43H          [0m[0m[10;37HOFF[0m[0m[10;41H [0m[0m[10;11HOK[0m                [0m[22;21H0.45  [7mTOO FEW BUTTONS[0m [0m[12;37HOFF[0m[0m[12;41H [0m[0m[12;43H [0m[0m[11;37HOFF[0m         [0m[11;41H20%[0m[0m[11;46H [0m[0m[21;44HOK   [0m [0m[14;44HOK   [0m[7m[9;37HFAIL[0m[0m[12;1H                    [0m[3;38H19:07:49 15-Sep-21
[4;20H02:00:00 
[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[23;10HAlarmbox Communications Fault.[11;11H26.88[13;20H45.1K [14;20H48.5K [14;36H55.9K [15;20H56.6K [15;36H58.0K [7;17H306  002  33 45  50 70
[7;41H42.4%[7;48H42.7%[3;0H OR0122-1 0122
```

Desired text file output:

```
current 463.70A
15:41:08 19-Sep-21
02:00:00 
Alarmbox Communications Fault.Alarmbox Communications Fault.Alarmbox Communications Fault.1126R1124R1060R1038R127.4R20.6R20.8R15.310.591W 15:41:09 19-Sep-21
02:00:00 
Alarmbox Communications Fault.Alarmbox Communications Fault.Alarmbox Communications Fault.OK   
OK   
HE WARN           OFF           OFF OK                0.46  TOO FEW BUTTONS OFF  OFF         20% OK    OK   FAIL                    15:41:10 19-Sep-21
02:00:00 
Alarmbox Communications Fault.Alarmbox Communications Fault.Alarmbox Communications Fault.26.7345.1K 48.5K 56.6K 56.6K 58.0K 306  002  33 45  50 70
42.4%42.8% OR0122-1 0122
```

Comment: `[3;38H`  looks like an ansii color or format escape sequence...that would be very strange for a serial interface to return ...

Comment: you get special codes used in Linux Terminals to set colors. If you run in IDLE then probably it sends it to terminal and it uses it to change colors. But when you send to file then it saves all these codes with other text. I don't know method to filter it. You would have to check char by char and if you get `[` then skip until `H`. Simply your problem is not pyserial but program which is used on `/dev/ttyUSB0`